# How to get hex number as a string in Python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, hex

What I'm looking for is a method to get a hex number as a string just like it is and not interpreted as unicode.

So if I have this '\xff' I want to get a string "ff" and not some unusual unicode character. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: Do you have a string, or a bytes object? If the latter, just use e.g. `format(b'\xff'[0], 'x')`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to represent such numbers in your code as string literals `r` (*raw* string literal) might be helpful:

```
my_hex_str = r'\xff'
```

But if you have a string `\xde\xad\xbe\xef` in memory already you can just split it by `\x`.

```
my_hex_str = input()  # returns `\xde\xad\xbe\xef`
print(''.join(my_hex_str.split(r'\x')))
```